# using map method the new object is not inserting

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I am trying to add a new object using the map, but the new object is not inserted, i think there is an issue with my logic,

What I am trying to is I have some results data, I am trying to structure it, the English 1st part will be an object and English 2nd part will be another object, these 2 objects will be inside children, like the example

```
[
{
    title: "English",
    children: [
      0:{
        title: "1ST",
        children: [
          {
            title: "CQ",
            dataIndex: "CQ",
          },
          {
            title: "MCQ",
            dataIndex: "MCQ",
          },
        ],
      },
      1:{
        title: "2ND",
        children: [
          {
            title: "CQ",
            dataIndex: "CQ",
          },
          {
            title: "MCQ",
            dataIndex: "MCQ",
          },
        ],
      }
]
```

Here is my code, the English 2nd part is not inserting

```js
  const results = [
    { Field: "english_1st_CQ" },
    { Field: "english_1st_MCQ" },
    { Field: "english_2nd_CQ" },
    { Field: "english_2nd_MCQ" },
  ];

  const structureData = (results) => {
    let arr = [];
    results.map((value) => {
      if (value.Field.includes("_")) {
        const [subjectName, subjectPart, suffix] = value.Field.split("_");
        const isSubjectExist = arr.find((el) => el.title == subjectName);
        if (isSubjectExist !== undefined) {
          isSubjectExist.children.map((element, i) => {
            if (element.title == subjectPart) {
              element = {
                title: subjectPart,
                children: [
                  {
                    title: suffix,
                    dataIndex: suffix,
                  },
                ],
              };
            } else {
              element.children["2"] = {
                title: suffix,
                dataIndex: suffix,
              };
            }
          });
        } else {
          const subject = {
            title: subjectName,
            children: [
              {
                title: subjectPart,
                children: [
                  {
                    title: suffix,
                    dataIndex: suffix,
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          };
          arr.push(subject);
        }
      }
    });
    return arr;
  };
  console.log(structureData(results));
```

The issue is here:

```
                if (element.title == subjectPart) {
                  element = {
                    title: subjectPart,
                    children: [
                      {
                        title: suffix,
                        dataIndex: suffix,
                      },
                    ],
                  };
```

Comment: assigning to the function argument `element` does not assign to `isSubjectExist.children[i]` - you could do `Object.assign(element, { tilte: ...... etc})` instead - not sure why you're using `map` ... you should be using `.forEach` since you don't care what `map` returns (and it returns an array of `undefined` anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using a functional approach helps to better keep track of and reason about what is happening during the iterations because it keeps things [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```js
function resolveNode (arr, title) {
  const node = arr.find(node => node.title === title) ?? {title, children: []};
  if (!arr.includes(node)) arr.push(node);
  return node;
}

function parse (input) {
  const result = [];
  for (const {Field} of input) {
    const [subject, part, suffix] = Field.split('_');
    const s = resolveNode(result, subject);
    const p = resolveNode(s.children, part);
    // Don't create duplicates:
    if (!p.children.find(node => node.title === suffix)) {
      p.children.push({title: suffix, dataIndex: suffix});
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const input = [
  { Field: "english_1st_CQ" },
  { Field: "english_1st_MCQ" },
  { Field: "english_2nd_CQ" },
  { Field: "english_2nd_MCQ" },
];

const result = parse(input);
const formattedJson = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
console.log(formattedJson);
```

Comment: Appreciate your help,